# UISearchBar briefly displays gray background when returning to title from a show segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a customized `UISearchController` with a custom `UISearchBar` as the title of a navigation controller, so that there's a persistent search bar control visible throughout the changes of child view controllers, which is shown in the first image of my gallery (not enough reputation to post images yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFPCq.jpg

However, when a user taps a search result displayed in a child table view controller, the navigation title is replaced with a text string, so that it looks like the second image in my gallery.

The problem occurs when I navigate back to the table view showing the search results, because for a brief moment, the search bar has a light gray background that looks like the third image in my gallery.

And when I slow down the animations in the simulator, I'm able to enter the Debug View Hierarchy in Xcode to see what the offending element is, which turns out to be a UIImageView named "UISearchBarBackground" that exists only until the transition animation ends, and the color snaps back to the intended result, as shown in the fourth image in my gallery.

In the initial view controller that initializes and sets the properties of my `UISearchController`, I've set the following properties of the search bar in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let controller = CustomSearchController(searchResultsController: self.searchResultsController)
controller.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
controller.searchBar.backgroundImage = nil
```

...and I have these custom classes, which I implemented so that I could get rid of the search controller's cancel button, which won't stay removed with delegate statements:

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    override func setShowsCancelButton(_ showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)

    }
}

class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {

    lazy var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
    [unowned self] in

        let customSearchBar = CustomSearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)        
        return customSearchBar

    }()

    override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
        return _searchBar
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can understand, at no point is my custom search controller deinitialized, and it is only initialized once, so I feel like the problem is appearing because of the drawing cycle, which temporarily places a visible view with a gray background before my settings take effect.

I'm pretty much at a loss as to what exactly is going on here, and how to solve this issue. I'm wondering if I'm just overlooking something simple, or if I instead have to create a custom transition object to solve the problem. I'm about an intermediate level with iOS architecture and Swift, but am always looking to learn more.

Comment: set tint color to .clear rather than background color

Comment: Setting `controller.searchBar.tintColor` to `UIColor.clear` or any other color makes no difference, although it seems I was able to solve my problem by setting `controller.searchBar.barTintColor` to the same green color as my main navigation (setting `barTintColor` to `UIColor.clear` results in a black background during the segue transition animation.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out that this issue is caused by not having a value set to the optional `barTintColor` property of `UISearchBar`. If the property is `nil` during a transition animation, then the view will appear light gray until the animation ends. To solve the problem, I set `controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 203/255, blue: 124/255, alpha: 1)`, and now I'm getting the intended results.